# Simple Bootstrap theme not working on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded this basic header theme, and added to my index.php on localhost, using uwamp. [Click here for link](https://demo.tutorialzine.com/2016/09/freebie-5-beautiful-bootstrap-headers/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- Generate classes to fix InternetExplorer bugs -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
 
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie ie7"> <![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie ie8"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie ie9"> <![endif]--> 

<head>

<!-- ~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- Set the website title -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

<title></title>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- Google Webmasters code for the website -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

<meta name="google-site-verification" content="">

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- Meta tags for the website seo -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language"   content="hu-hu">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="robots" content="">
<meta name="revisit-after" content="">
<meta name="distribution" content="local">
<meta name="language" content="hu">
<meta name="rating" content="general">

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- Add OpenGraph meta tags for sharing the website -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

<meta property="og:title" content="">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property="og:url" content="">
<meta property="og:locale" content="hu_HU">

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- Add the websites base href link -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

<!--<base href="">-->

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- Canonical link -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

<link href="" rel="canonical">

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- Add the favicon to the website -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

<link href="/images/assets/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
<link href="/images/assets/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- Include css style files -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navigation-clean-button">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
             <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#">First Item</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Second Item</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="navbar-text navbar-right actions"><a class="navbar-link login" href="#">Log In</a> <a class="btn btn-default action-button" role="button" href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>


<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- Include jQuery library, Bootstrap responsive framework, and other javascript files -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If i view the site source in the browser, i can find and open all the css and js files, so the way to the files is correct.

My problem is, that i dont get anything on the page, no css style, i cant see the nac items...Only just the logo text.

Whats going wrong? The bootstrap css and js are downloaded from the offical bootstrap site. I commented the base href also, beacuse the site isnt on a server.

Comment: Correct the file relative path according to your folder structure. You can do it by yourself.

Comment: Try to start your paths to files with `/`

Comment: Do you get any error in your developer console?

Comment: Yes, i get this:  Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined
    at bootstrap.min.js:sourcemap:6

Comment: And if i view the console elements, i cant see the nav, the links..nothing. Only the Company Name logo text.

Comment: If i give full path in the href, still nothing.

Comment: And if i create a simple html file of the index.php, and than copy the folder to the desktop, that doesnt works. Same problem.